# Maclaurin Series with Power in Denominator?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, power-series

$$f(x) = \frac {x}{({125+6x^2})^{1/3}}
$$

I'm having a bit of a tough time trying to figure out this question (in which I'm supposed to find the first five coefficients after creating a Maclaurin series representation, a=0).

When raised to the power of whole numbers I know how to move my way towards $ \frac {1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}X^{n}$ by taking derivatives/integrals and find the overall summation that way. With that said, I'm a bit confused on how to deal with powers like $ \frac {1}{3}$ in the denominator. Of course, you could also do out a number of derivatives, evaluate at 0, and try to find a common representation that way (but I just get all zeroes that way).

I hope this isn't a terribly easy question, but I'm not sure where to even begin and have had a hard time finding comparable examples with an x numerator and some power <1 in the denominator.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that :
$$(1+x)^a = 1 + ax + \frac{a(a-1)}{2!}x^2 + \frac{a(a-1)(a-2)}{3!}x^3 + ... + \frac{a(a-1)(a-2)...(a-n)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1} + o(x^{n+1})$$

So here, use $a = -\frac{1}{3}$.

You need to get it in the form $\alpha(1+u)^a$ so here :
$$(125+6x^2)^a = (125(1+\frac{6}{125}x^2))^a= 125^{a}(1+\frac{6}{125}x^2)^a$$

e.g. for order 3 :
$$(1+x)^{-1/3} = 1 - \frac{1}{3}x + \frac{2}{9}x^2 - \frac{14}{81}x^3 +o(x^3)$$
Composing with $\frac{6}{125}x^2$ gives : 
$$(1+\frac{6}{125}x^2)^{-1/3} = 1 - \frac{2}{125}x^2 +o(x^3)$$ (as you compose, you don't keep any term over 3rd order..)

Then multiply by $125^{-1/3}x$.

$$\frac{1}{5}x - \frac{2}{625}x^3 + o(x^3)$$

Comment: Oh, you can express it as a binomial series! I had that written down, but thought it didn't quite look right so didn't pursue it any further. Thanks very much!

Comment: @PTiger17 : Sometimes, derivating might look a better idea though.. This one is quite 'computational', quite much tedious calculus !